# How to detect if kafka broker is not available from consumer in java?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a simple Kafka consumer in Java. I'm trying to catch an exception if Kafka broker is not available. I need it to interrupt the thread.

I have code like this:

```
KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(kafkaConsumerProperties());
kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));
try {
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(500);
    // records handling
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}finally {
    kafkaConsumer.close();
}
```

If Kafka server is down I don't catch any exceptions but following messages are displayed in log:

```
18/03/28 13:33:39 WARN clients.NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=JAVA] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
18/03/28 13:33:40 WARN clients.NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=JAVA] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

Is there a way to handle it in my thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem somewhat clumsy, but it works for me.

```
public boolean testSocket(String serversList) {        
    String[] sockets = serversList.split(",");
    int unactive = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sockets.length; i++) {
        try {
            String[] socket = sockets[i].split(":");
            (new Socket(socket[0], Integer.valueOf(socket[1]))).close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            unactive++;
        }
    }
    if (unactive < sockets.length) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can work :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Starting exit...");
                consumer.wakeup(); 1
                try {
                    mainThread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

You do `consumer.wakeup()` to interrupt current consumer's operation.

The `mainThread.join()` is put in there to ensure that main thread actually finishes and is not shut down in middle of processing after wakeup. Please remember that shutdownHook is responsible for handling interrupts as well, not only ordinary program shutdown.