# How to make kafka consumer stop retrying and crash when broker is not available?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Currently, when broker is not available, I see that java consumer will try to reconnect to broker for infinite amount of time(or at least I was not able to wait till it stops).

What I would like to have is an ability to have an exception thrown from `poll()` when broker is not available. Or maybe some other way, but I want my app to crash when broker is not available. It seems that it should be very easy to configure, but I'm unable to find info anywhere.

Here is an example. It'll always return 0 records from poll and will retry connection to broker forever.

```
package org.example;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Consumer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9094");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test-consumer-group");
        try (KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props)) {
            consumer.subscribe(List.of("game.journal"));
            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> recs = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> rec : recs) {
                    System.out.printf("Recieved %s: %s", rec.key(), rec.value());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So how can I make consumer crash when broker is not available?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect if kafka broker is not available from consumer in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49532645/how-to-detect-if-kafka-broker-is-not-available-from-consumer-in-java)

Comment: Well, probably I would love to have something more robust, but it could work I think, need to try it. Just strange that kafka decided to retry forever for some reason. Thank you for the link.